Laurent expansion of modular functions
I am studying "A Course in Arithmetic", by Serre, and he says that, since modular functions are periodic, we can express them as functions of $q=e^{2\pi iz}$, which are denoted now by $\tilde{f}$.
After some reasoning, he says that $\tilde{f}$ admits a Laurent expansion in a neighborhood of the origin, given by $$\tilde{f}(q)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n q^n,$$ where the $a_n$ are zero of $n$ small enough (which is the case for $\tilde{f}$ extends to a meromorphic function at the origin) or $n<0$ (which is the case for $\tilde{f}$ extends to a holomorphic function at the origin).
I didn't understand the last phrase, the one about the $a_n$. In a Laurent expansion, according to my internet research, we have that $$a_n=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-p)^{n+1}}dz.$$ In my case, we obtain $$a_n=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \dfrac{\tilde{f}(q)}{q^{n+1}}dz.$$ So, in order to $\tilde{f}(q)$ be holomorphic, $n\leq -1$, according to Serre. But $q(z)=e^{2\pi i z}\neq 0$, so in my head it seems that $n$ could be anything.
Furthermore, this was all in relation to holomorphicity. About the meromorphicity, I don't even know how to begin the reasoning.

Holomorphic functions have power series,  hence the coefficients $a_n$ in a proposed Laurent series are zero for $n\lt0.$  For a meromorphic function it can be written as a quotient of polynomials,  and hence has finitely many singularities.   Hence only finitely many $a_n$ are nonzero,  for $n\lt0.$

I think understood the holomorphic part. But why do $a_n$'s different from $0$ generate polos ($n<0$)?

Meromorphic functions don't have essential singularities. Thus only finitely many negative terms.   Not sure this addresses your issue.

I did not understand why an $a_n\neq 0$ produces a singularity for $n<0$. It is a doubt of complex analysis, I think.

Because $a_{-n}\frac 1{(z-p)^n}$ isn't defined at $p,$ essentially.

That's the simplest example.   If you have more such terms (higher negative powers), you still have a problem.

I think I understood now. Thank you so much!
